# How to run a batch file every time a command is executed?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

Is there any way to pass the parameters passed through cmd including the file name to an batch file which would then decide if the executable should execute or not?

eg.

```
@echo off
if "%lockcmd%"=="" execmd %*
```

Comment: It is possible, but its highly recommended not to go this route. If you make a mistake, you may make it impossible to run any command anymore until you reinstall windows. Also keep in mind, that anyone could alter the batch file to grand their program. Its not fool proof. It is better to use the tools that were meant for this kind of question, Group Policies.

Comment: Could you please suggest some other way to program-matically achieve it?

Comment: Something which could just be executed to set things up

Comment: Normally, if a pc is domain joined, you configure the group policy once, and all pc's affected by that group policy automatically get this setting. That is how you are supposed to set this up.

Comment: I want to locally set up this feature for a single computer

Comment: If you have a pro version or enterprise version, you can use GPEdit.msc and accomplish the same thing. Do note that a misconfigure here is as dangarous as your bachfile approach, but it is at least a whole lot harder to figure out for a non-techy person.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home and you can feel free to use technical terms if you wish to.

Comment: Windows 10 Home has no Group Policy management, so that is not going to work. I recommend searching for a program that can do what you want. For example, look into kiosk mode or similar programs.

Comment: Is there some other way to do it? Windows Reg. /  `ftype` / `assoc`

Comment: Can I do something in File Explorer?

Comment: eg. Files with .txt extensions can be opened using Notepad via `cmd`

Comment: I don't see any reason why it cant be done. But I am curious about the decision process, what the factors are that would determine if its a (go/no go) situation? Is it based on the parameters passed to it? Environment variables? How exactly will you decide?  What if the deciding factors are in error, or someone intentionally tries to wreak havoc? Maybe if you could elaborate a little more on the goals and decision processes, we could be of more help.

Comment: Could you please post an answer to achieve it? @Larryc?